# VBA code not working unless specific sheet is active

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to cut and move rows to another worksheet if certain cells meet criteria. Below code works  when the "Trading" worksheet is active; but I got

> 'Runtime error 1004'

if I run it when I was on other worksheet.

```
Sub GetMarketingRows()

Dim TradingStock As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim AllItems As Range

Set TradingStock = Worksheets("Trading")
Set AllItems = TradingStock.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

For r = AllItems.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1

    If (TradingStock.Cells(r, 8) Like "Marketing" Or Cells(r, 7) Like "F-Marketing") Then
    TradingStock.Rows(r).EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Marketing").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    TradingStock.Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete

    End If

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: You did not qualify this range object with a sheet reference: `Range("A1").End(xlDown)`

Answer (score 1):

Fix the code with

```
Set AllItems = TradingStock.Range("A1", TradingStock.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

your second `Range()` was scoped to the `ActiveSheet`.

Also, this needs fixing

```
   Destination:=Worksheets("Marketing").Cells( AllItems.Rows.Count, 1)
```

as your `Rows.Count` was also using `ActiveSheet`.